# How do I convert a hex file to its equivalent char file?

Tags: c

I have a file which contains "hello world". I have converted it to hex file "68656c6c6f20776f726c640a". Now I want it to convert the hex file to its original content. How can I do it? I tried getting a char from the hex file and converting it to its equivalent character, but every time it is picking up one char 6 instead of 68. Please help.

```
int main()
{
     FILE *fp, *fptr;
     char c;
     fp = fopen ( "example1.txt", "r" ) ;
     fptr = fopen ( "example2.txt", "w" );
     while ( (c=fgetc(fp)) != EOF )
     {
          fputc(c, fptr);
     }
     fclose (fp);
     fclose(fptr);
     return 0;
}
```

expected output: hello world
output I'm getting: 68656c6c6f20776f726c640a

Comment: Note that [`fgetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) return an **`int`**, which is actually very important for the comparison to the `int` value `EOF`.

Comment: And if you have a text file containing those digits as text where each digit is a single character, then that's what `fgetc` will read: Those exact characters. It doesn't do any translation, and don't know anything about numbers (hexadecimal or not). You need to convert the characters to numbers, combine two numeric digits into the correct two-digit number, and then use that as a "character" to output.

Comment: If I can read two characters at a time from the file and treat them as a single character and then convert it to its equivalent character, then the problem is solved.

Comment: You can't treat two characters as a single character, but you can convert each character to its corresponding numerical value, combine the two values, and use that combined value as a character. All you need is simple arithmetic (subtraction, addition and multiplication).

Comment: Also when I tried to convert the character to number, I got the ascii value of each character. For example 6 is converted to 54 and so on. How can I get an integer 6 instead of 54?

Comment: The C specification says that all digit characters needs to be consecutively encoded, with `'0'` first and `'9'` last. For example with [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) (the most common character encoding bar none) the value for `'0'` is `48` and the value for `'9'` is `57`. Now armed with that information it should be very easy to figure out a way to get from the encoded character value to its numerical equivalent... Hint: Subtraction is involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read two digits as a hex value, this will convert them back to a character:

like:

```
 int tmp;
 while ( fscanf(fp,"%2x",&tmp) > 0 )
 {      
     fputc(tmp, fptr);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed as pointed in the comments, you should read 2 consecutives characters, combine them (e.g. using strtol) into a hex number (hex representation of the ASCII value) and then write it into the output file as a character. Following code tested on VS2019:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#pragma warning(disable: 4996)

int main()
{
FILE* fp, * fptr;
char c1,c2;
fp = fopen("c:\\temp\\example1.txt", "r");
fptr = fopen("c:\\temp\\example2.txt", "w");
while ((c1 = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
{
    unsigned char to_ascii;
    char s1[2] = { '\0','\0' }, s2[2] = { '\0','\0' };

    c2 = fgetc(fp);

    s1[0] = c1;
    s2[0] = c2;     

    to_ascii = 16 * strtol(s1,NULL,16) + strtol(s2, NULL,16);

    fprintf(fptr, "%c", to_ascii);
}
fclose(fp);
fclose(fptr);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read pairs of characters and convert them.  To convert a digit character's charset value to its digit value, subtract `'0'`.  To convert a hex digit `a-f` or `A-F` to 10-15, subtract `'A'` or `'a'`, and add 10.

Putting it all together:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>  /* for isdigit, etc.    */

int hexdigitval(int c)
{
    if(isdigit(c)) return c - '0';
    if(isupper(c)) return c - 'A' + 10;
    if(islower(c)) return c - 'a' + 10;
    /* can't happen */
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int c1, c2;
    int d1, d2;
    int newc;

    while((c1 = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if(!isxdigit(c1)) continue;
        c2 = getchar();
        if(c2 == EOF) break;
        if(!isxdigit(c2)) continue;
        d1 = hexdigitval(c1);
        d2 = hexdigitval(c2);
        newc = 16 * d1 + d2;
        putchar(newc);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why posting this answer since the answer from @SHR was posted before and is much easier ?

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean Well, because I thought it might be useful and/or instructive, of course.